# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer: Octokit

Tags: ruby, iteration, octokit

This is just an example of the reponse body

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    }
  ],
  "teams": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VGVhbTE=",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/teams/1",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/orgs/github/teams/justice-league",
      "name": "Justice League",
      "slug": "justice-league",
      "description": "A great team.",
      "privacy": "closed",
      "permission": "admin",
      "members_url": "https://api.github.com/teams/1/members{/member}",
      "repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/teams/1/repos",
      "parent": null
    }
  ]
}
```

```
 client.pull_request_reviewer("healtheintent/hcc_reference_service", 129).each do |comment|
    username = comment[:user][:login]
end
```

This is the code I am using to iterate the given response.
But its returning  "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer "

Can someone please tell me how I iterate the given body

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. We need the minimal code that is runnable and capable of reproducing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your "path" of accessing the content (comment[:user][:login]) does absolutely not match your datastructure.

1. its `users` not `user`
2. the root object is a hash, not an array
3. you have a nested array, which you are not iterating over

maybe you want this

```
client.pull_request_reviewer("healtheintent/hcc_reference_service", 129)[:users].each do |user|
    username = user[:login]
```

the reason you are getting a "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" is, because you are using the `[]` notation on an array, but giving it a symbol as key/index (because you wrongly assumed to be a hash)

Comment: The error will occur at `comment[:user]` because  `Hash#each` will yield `[key,value]` since th OP did not expand these args per the usual `do |k,v|` the `comment` is set you the yielded `Array`. Similar to `comment=[x, y]` vs `k, v = [x, y]`; however had this not occurred `v[:login]` would have resulted in an identical error.